# Xamarin.Forms + Master Detail + TalkBack on Androind

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, master-pages, talkback

I made custom renderer for NavigationPageRenderer but I cant change the burger menu button ContentDescription. It reads burger menu button as "OK" button. Do you have some ideas?

Comment: @ChrisCM and which crossplatform do you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a `ImageButton` in Android platform. So you can change the image source of this hamburger button to implement this feature.

You could use [Custom Renderers](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/) to create a custom `MasterDetailPage`, here is an example:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MasterDetailPage), typeof(MyMasterDetailRenderer))]
...
public class MyMasterDetailRenderer : MasterDetailPageRenderer
{
    public MyMasterDetailRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
    {
        base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        var toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
        for (var i = 0; i < toolbar.ChildCount; i++)
        {
            var imageButton = toolbar.GetChildAt(i) as ImageButton;

            var drawerArrow = imageButton?.Drawable as DrawerArrowDrawable;
            if (drawerArrow == null)
                continue;

            imageButton.SetImageDrawable(Context.GetDrawable(Resource.Mipmap.hamburger));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you also help me with my .resx files? how can I get them there?

Comment: @MilanMiNoMichalec, I would suggest you open a new ticket in SO about your issue, :)